# WinUI3: How to style datagrid group header text?

Tags: datagrid, windows-community-toolkit, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I am using [the Windows Community Toolkit DataGrid control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/communitytoolkit.winui.ui.controls.datagrid?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0) in my WinUI3 project.

I would like to make the group header text bold. How can I do this?

Currently the group header looks like this (not bold):

[image: group header, not bold]

I have tried setting styles:

```xaml
<ctWinUI:DataGrid ...>
    <ctWinUI:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
        <Style TargetType="ctWinUI:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
            <Setter Property="PropertyNameVisibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemCountVisibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>  <!--Ignored-->
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>  <!--Ignored-->
        </Style>
    </ctWinUI:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
    ...
</ctWinUI:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to override the `BodyTextBlockStyle` theme resource:

```xaml
<ctWinUI:DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BodyTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
</ctWinUI:DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Wow, works great, thanks!